# How to remove the URI from URL using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, server

I have a virtualhost called **test.com** and when I enter the module that I am developing now it is **test.com/module** but i need to remove the URI to perform necessary processes where i do not require the URI until after.

When loading the page shows me **test.com** and when i access the module i get **test.com/module**.
I need to access the module continue showing me **test.com** for what when doing an **echo** to **$_SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]** it shows me '//' and not the host nor the uri

Regards.

**Note: I am using apache**

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact php code you used, but there is a misspelling in `$_SERVER ["REUQEST_URI"]`. This should be `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: Sorry, i have finger error, i need remove the part of module from URL.
**test.com/module** to **test.com** but without disturbing the view or functionality

Answer (score 3):

A parse_url() example

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

OR You can use strtok to get string before first occurence of ?

```
$url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
```

Comment: Thanks but i have $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] this gives me the URI and i need  to remove from **test.com/module** the URI and get **test.com**

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to parse the domain part of the URL, you can use

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
```

Comment: Ok, but when i do echo to **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** print me **test.com** but i need print only `//` as if it were the root of the host

Comment: Sorry, It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you give an example of what you need?

Comment: I have **test.com/module** which is the URL of my module but i need remove the part of **/module** from URL to get, in the URL only **test.com**  and so, although i have visually and the functionality of the module i need to make echo **$ _SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]** only print me `//` and not the URL or the URI 
as if it were displaying the root of the host being executed

Comment: You want to always print `//` no matter what the URL is? Or you want the absolute PHP path? In that case, use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. Otherwise, please give an example.

Comment: I want print `//` for the first time charge the page, but the first time I charge it it throws me **test.com/module** and i need to do a **echo** to **$ _SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]** show `//` and not **/module /**

Comment: So you want the output `//`, no matter what input? Then you would only need `echo '//'` but I guess you understood that already. After 5 replies I'm still not sure what you want to achieve, maybe you could ask someone to translate your question for you.